# Is it a good practice to define Date fields of Persistent entities as Long type, so that we store millis in that field?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Whenever I create Persistent entities (such as JPA Entity POJOs), I define the "date" fields with type: java.util.Date

I am considering storing such fields as "Long"  type, having the milliseconds value.

During sql retrieval queries, this millisecond value can be used to create Data Pojos: Calendar.getInstance().setTimeInMillis(millis)

I think operations such as Sorting, Locale Conversion, would be much faster if such fields are stored as numeric types (Long).

Does anybody know the pros-n-cons of defining such fields as java.util.Date vs Long millis ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Date. The class inside uses a long, so you can create equivalent code.

What are you losing without the class is type safety and overall program semantics.

What can you get is very small performance improvement in cases when you deal just with the long, when you are not creating any new Date or new Calendar.